# DAQ sound acquisition

Tags: microphone, sound, condenser-microphone, daq

I have a simple USB [DAQ device](https://www.monodaq.com/usb-daq/multifunctional/) ([datasheet](https://www.monodaq.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/06/DataSheet_MonoDAQ-U-X_v1.6_2022-06-01.pdf)). I was hoping that with differential voltage I would be able to measure simple sounds and convert/store them as a simple audio file (e.g. WAV, MP3). I see there are many DAQs designed to capture sound signals, but currently these are beyond my budget.

I tried connecting a simple condenser microphone with a 2 V operating voltage, powered by the EXC output (voltage source) of the DAQ. However, no reproducible sound (or signal) was obtained.

Microphone:
[image]

I used this configuration (50 ksamples/s, 16 bits):
[image]

Comment: A sound card is a DAQ designed to capture audio. It probably has a way nicer ADC bitdepth than what you can buy as "classical" DAQ, and is optimized for audio/microphone levels. Use a soundcard, for example that built into your PC/Laptop/smartphone/tablet.

Comment: It is unclear how you powered and connected the supply and analog input to the microphone. It is unclear also what is the input impedance of DAQ and if the voltage range and bandwidth are suitable for audio. Simply put, for audio, use a sound card. They have mic ports designed to connect to mics and designed to capture audio.

Comment: Thank you for quick answer. Of course, I would use soundcard, however, what I need is concomitant "other" voltage measurement, that is why I wanted a DAQ: to be able to simultaneously capture voltage (other source) AND sound (as voltage?) on 'separate channels'. I am new to SE, should I edit/reframe/clarify the question?

Comment: I think it will suffice of you draw how you connected the microphone to DAQ so we can see what the problem is. But if the connections are correct, based on DAQ datasheet it is impossible to determine if the input impedance is suitable for the mic.

Comment: one note, the datasheet says you can only do 20 kS/s divided through the number of channels if using more than 1 channel. So, you cannot simultaneously capture your microphone and another source. Do 10 kS/s suffice to correctly represent the audio (i.e., is the highest frequency you want to capture with the microphone < 5 kHz)? And: something is a bit wrong about the blue curve in the figure "Analog input frequency response – multi channel mode (mux), buffered single-ended input, different sample rates": It should stop at 5 kHz, but lets through up to 40 kHz(-ish)? you will need an AA filter!